# MongoDB & CodeIgniter: Select where a field exists

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb, field

I'm working with Codeigniter and the [MongoDb library](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/tree/v2).

I would like to perform a select where a field exists.

```
db.yourcollection.find({ 'otherInfo.text' : { '$exists' : true }})
```

But I can't find how to do that with this library...

Any solutions please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a CI programmer here but I would think:

```
$this->mongo_db->where(array('otherInfo.text'=>array('$exists'=>true)))
```

would work.