# MongoDB: find a field exist in document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have written an script for mongodb at robo 3t. but i want to check my document that has not specific field and then my script run. that is mean if **Doamin** is exist my script do not run.
I see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467030/mongodb-codeigniter-select-where-a-field-exists)

but I do not understand well, what can i do!

```
db.Events.find().forEach(function (item) {
id = item._id;
businessCode = item.BusinessCode

// check Domain filed exist or not
// if (Domain : { $exists: false }) {  // does not work and I got error
```

this is my document:

```
"BusinessCode" : "1-2-4-4-5-6-9",
"ProcessId" : UUID("55657890-4433-3993-7933-119876543299"),
"WorkItemId" : NumberLong(423458),
"Domain" : "1"
```

in some documents **Domain** is not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `Domain` does not exists in documents within the `query` as:

```
 db.Events.find({"Domain":{$exists:false}}).forEach(function (item) { ...
```